# Transpiling single TypeScript file with Typings

Tags: node.js, typescript

Im trying to get a single TypeScript file that references Node.js objects to transpile.

**test.ts**

```
import { resolve } from 'path';

console.log(`test:  ${resolve(__dirname)}`);
```

I'm attempting to compile this file from the command line using `tsc test.ts` and receive the following errors:

> test.ts(2,25): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'path'.
> test.ts(4,41): error TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.

I have a `tsconfig.json` in my root, and I've also installed Typings with the proper node.js declarations.

**What works:**

- Running with `tsc` by itself -but this transpiles all ts files in project
- Adding a reference to test.ts to the declaration

  `/// <reference path="typings/globals/node/index.d.ts" />`

Is it not possible to transpile a single file from TypeScript using the definitions available within the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Typescript 1.x you have to put a reference path in each file for anything you reference as an import.  You can still use `var foo = require("bar")` without adding the reference path.  If you can upgrade to Typescript 2.x, you can specify the `typeRoots` property in the `tsconfig.json` and you can then exclude the reference path, the compiler will just parse through whatever directory you specify.